# SQL Command not properly Ended

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Tried running a java method that runs this oracle SQL query

```
String query =
            "SELECT count(*) " +
            "FROM TASK t " +
            "WHERE t.TASK_ID = ? ";
```

I keep getting SQL Command not properly Ended

Printed the string and got this output
SELECT count(*) FROM TASK t WHERE t.TASK_ID = ?

*edited to reflect new changes, the method basically looks for the taskID and if it exists return true, otherwise false.

```
public boolean loadTaskId(Integer taskId) throws SQLException{

    int count = 0;

    String query =
            "SELECT count(*) " +
            "FROM TASK t " +
            "WHERE t.TASK_ID = ?";

    OraclePreparedStatement stmt = prepareStatement(query);
    stmt.setInt(1, taskId);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) { // only load the first one
        count = rs.getInt(1);
    }
    stmt.close();
    if ( count == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "select count(*)from task twhere t.jdeis_task_id = ?" is not valid sql.  Consider printing the query as part of your debugging when you get errors.

Comment: I'm using OraclePreparedStatement so after I set up the query String I set up the values of ?'s

Comment: replaced the ? with numbers and tried it too still not working

Comment: Can you post the other relevant code - your prepared statement, assigning the parameter value, executing the query...?

Comment: @synergy The root of my comment is "twhere" is not valid.  This was caused by the lack of trailing spaces in your strings while constructing your query (as stated by JW in his/her answer)

Comment: oh sorry i misinterpreted it, I added the spaces and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out whats wrong, I didn't delete the .jar file in the library and it had some name conflicts going on and wasn't rebuilding. *slaps my own head

Answer (score 9):

You might want to modify your SQL statement to include some spaces:

```
String query =
        "SELECT count(*) " +
        "FROM TASK t " +
        "WHERE t.TASK_ID = ?";
```

That's probably the problem. You can print the string out to System.out to confirm.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that thanks, but its still not working, giving same error.

Comment: @JW isn't `?` the JDBC variable placeholder character?

Comment: yep so instead of ? i just put 2000, but using the oraclepreparedstatement

Comment: got SELECT count(*) FROM TASK t WHERE t.TASK_ID = ? as the output after I printed the String

Comment: Just to confirm - if you run the above SQL directly in Oracle, do you get an error or a valid resultset?

Comment: when I run it in Toad it says missing expression

Comment: The statement needs to be fixed. Does this simplified version of the query work: SELECT count(*) FROM Task WHERE Task_ID = ?

Comment: okay I was stupid, I forgot to replace the info i removed to hide private information.  So I ran the query SELECT count(*) FROM Task t WHERE t.TASK_ID = 2280 and it works.  So the method should technically work too

Answer (score 1):

```
String query =
            "SELECT count(*) " +
            "FROM TASK t " +
            "WHERE t.TASK_ID = ?";
```

You did not add spaces

Comment: `FROM TASK as t` won't work on Oracle. Oracle does not allow the `as` keyword for table aliasing. For example, `select * from dual as d` gives `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`. `select * from dual d` works.

Comment: I basically gave the right answer for a sql query but I did not now about this in oracles case